# Was Simon's hideout later used by Ralph?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies, william-golding

In the end of the third chapter of *Lord of the Flies,* Simon goes to his hideout.  It is described as having a great mat of creepers and being screened off by a few leaves.

Later, when he is being hunted, Ralph hides in the bushes, behind "a wild tangle of creeper" forming a mat that kept out all the light of the sun.  However, in the eighth chapter, Simon goes to his hideout and it is said that he cannot avoid the light of the sun.

**I could not help but notice the similarities in wording between the descriptions for the two places.**
**Are they the same place or not?**

Comment: Which chapter is it that Ralph hides in? I'm having some trouble finding it

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the last one, really close to the end.

Comment: Rahlp hid under a mat of creepers near the end of the book, while SImon had to squeeze into his hideout.